# Scaling fonts with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Various posts I've seen about using XeLaTeX suggest something like the following setup for fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\setotherlanguages{french,german}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is `Ligatures=TeX` actually needed, or is that already the default with `fontspec`?
2. What exactly does the option `Scale=MatchLowercase` accomplish there? I'm not seeing any difference in the output if I omit it.
3. Why is the option `Scale=1.0` needed in `\setmainfont`? I do see that omitting it shrinks the text font (see output below). But why are TeX Gyre Termes and TeX Gyre Termes Math not already designed to be compatible in size?

**Output:**

[image: Including Scale=1.0 option]

[image: Omitting Scale=1.0 option]

Comment: Answer to question 1: Yes. See documentation of `fontspec`, part II section 1, "the default setup for font loading automatically adds the `Ligatures=TeX` feature for the `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` commands."

Comment: Matchlowercase will scale the sans and mono spaced font so the height of  lowercase letters match the those of the main font. So you won’t see that in your example. The default scale of the main font may not necessarily be 1.0 and seems to be a bit lower for Termes. It appears that the scale of the math font matches that of the main font in your examples.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: The scale of the math font matches that of the main font in *both* sample outputs, no matter whether I include `Scale=1.0` or not?

Comment: @murray : looks that way to me.

Answer (score 4):

The `Ligatures=TeX` option is used by default for all fonts declared with `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`. How?

When `fontspec` is loaded, it looks for a `fontspec.cfg` file, with the usual precedence rules. If no local file is found, the global one is input, which contains

```latex
\defaultfontfeatures
 [\rmfamily,\sffamily]
 {Ligatures=TeX}

\defaultfontfeatures
 [\ttfamily]
 {WordSpace={1,0,0},
  HyphenChar=None,
  PunctuationSpace=WordSpace}
```

Declaring `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` can be useful for declaring other fonts with `\newfontfamily` or `\newfontface`. Beware to not do it with monospaced font families. Declaring it before loading any font would override the default and apply it also to `\setmonofont`, which is usually unwanted.

The options `Scale=MatchUppercase` or `Scale=MatchLowercase` make no sense before declaring the main font, because they'd scale the main font against Latin Modern.
They make little sense inside `\defaultfontfeatures` anyway, because fonts have usually quite different ideas on how the x-height compares to the full height of the glyphs, so judgment has to be applied for each font.

Of course `Scale=1.0` is not needed if you don't apply scaling beforehand.

Comment: So exactly what *should* the order of the commands be in that preamble block starting at `\usepackage{fontspec}` and ending at `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`?

Comment: @murray Just remove the `\defaultfontfeatures` line. And `Scale=1.0`

Comment: Now I'm really confused: Don't I need at least `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase` so that if I include another font, e.g. one for Cyrillic, it matches? And excluding `Scale=1.0`, as the output shows, does change the size of the main font while, it appears, keeping the math font properly scaled to match it.

Comment: @murray You ***may*** need it ***after*** the main declarations `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`. But, as I said, it mostly depends on ***what*** font families you load, because they might not all benefit from the same type of scaling. It's definitely wrong before `\setmainfont`. You want to scale fonts relatively to the main font, don't you? Not relatively to Latin Modern thay you may even be not using.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to question 1: Yes. See documentation of `fontspec`, part II section 1,

> ... the default setup for font loading automatically adds the `Ligatures=TeX` feature for the `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` commands.

To question 2: See documentation of `fontspec`, part II section 6.2,

> ... the `Scale` feature also accepts options `MatchLowercase` and `MatchUppercase`, which will scale the font being selected to match the current default roman font to either the height of the lowercase or uppercase letters, respectively; ...

To question 3: I guess it is used to override the default `Scale=MatchLowercase`. Otherwise the newly set roman font (by using `\setmainfont`) with be scaled to match default roman font Latin Modern Roman. (Not sure, need to be checked.)